# How to get word from text file BASH

Tags: bash

I want to get only one word from this txt file: http://pastebin.com/jFDu0Le5 . The word is from last row: `WER: 45.67%  Correct: 65.87%     Acc: 54.33%`
I want to get only the value: `45.67` to save it to the file `value.txt`..I want to create BASH script to get this value. Can  you give me an example how to do it??? I am new in Bash and I need it for school. The whole .txt file is saved on my server as text file `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep WER file.txt | awk '{print $2}' | uniq | sed -e 's/%//' > value.txt
```

Note that this will overwrite value.txt each time you run the command.

Answer (score 0):

You want grep "WER:" value.txt | cut -???

I have ??? because I do not know the structure of the file. Tab delimited? Fixed Width?

Do   man cut an you can get the arguments you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is as you said, then this also works

```
awk -F'[: %]' '/^WER/{print $3}' file.txt > value.txt
```

### Explanation

- `-F` specifies the field separator as one of `[: %]`
- `/<PATTERN>/ {<ACTION>}` refers to: if a line matches some PATTERN, then do some ACTION
- in my case,

  - the PATTERN is: starts with `^` the string `WER`
  - the ACTION is: `print` field `$3` (as split by the `-F` field separators)
- `>` sends the output to `value.txt`

Comment: `$0~/^WER/` is identical to `/^WER/` in a pattern.

Comment: @EtanReisner -- hahaha this is true! :)

Answer (score 0):

There a many ways and instruments to do the task:

### sed

```
tac file.txt | sed -n '/^WER: /{s///;s/%.*//;p;q}' > value.txt
```

### awk

```
tac file.txt | awk -F'[ %]' '/^WER:/{print $2;exit}' > value.txt
```

### bash

```
while read a b c
do
    if [ $a = "WER:" ]
    then
        b=${b%\%*}
        echo ${b#* }
        break
    fi
done < <(tac file.txt) > value.txt
```